# How to solve "pkg: No trusted certificates"

Tags: freebsd, pkgbuild

Freebsd 9.2 i386 Release

Problem:

I want to install gdb but i'm having trouble

Problem:

pkg: No trusted certificates
Unable to update repository FreeBSD

FreeBSD.conf

```
# cat /etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf
# $FreeBSD: release/10.0.0/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf 258710 2013-11-28 14:24:26Z gjb $
FreeBSD: {
  url: "pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/latest",
  mirror_type: "srv",
  signature_type: "fingerprints",
  fingerprints: "/usr/share/keys/pkg",
  enabled: yes
}
```

I get an error like this when I try to install keys

```
cd /usr/src/share/keys/pkg && make install
/usr/src/share/keys/pkg: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: You're probably running too old FreeBSD version.